# How do I reinstall ModelSim Student Edition?

Tags: windows-7

I have installed on my Windows [ModelSim Student Edition](http://model.com/content/modelsim-pe-student-edition-hdl-simulation) on my Windows 7 PC, but after uninstalling it and trying to reinstall it, the installer detects my MAC address or something and doesn't let me install it.

I deleted all the registry entries by searching for "modelsim" in `regedit`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking up the software [here](http://model.com/content/modelsim-pe-student-edition-hdl-simulation) - I noticed the instructions said that "If you need to re-install the software on a computer, you must go through the entire process of download, installation and submission of the license request form."

That would indicate that your installation is somehow locked to the licence request form rather than a mac address, and that going through the whole process again should fix it

Comment: it is not... I tried

Comment: Any specific error messages?

Comment: no... It unpacks the installer but doesn't run it, I thinks it checks something and then exit(0) or something.